# Inverse function theorem Proof in Rudin Book (Openness of V)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, inverse-function-theorem

In Proving the Inverse function theorem in Mathematical Analysis Book of Rudin, when he want to show that V is open, Why he simply does not use that under continuous function (Mapping), the open set U mapped to the open set V. He used this:
[image]

Comment: Continuous functions don't always map open sets to open sets.  That is, if $f$ is continuous and $U$ is an open set, then $f(U)$ may or may not be open.

Comment: There is one theorem for that but it needs continuity of inverse function which is not supposed here I think. I get my answer but do not close the question for now. Thanks

Comment: The essential example to think about here is $f(x) = x^2$. It you look for an inverse function about some point $(p, p^2)$ with $p \ne 0$, then you get either $+\sqrt y$ or $-\sqrt y$ depending on whether $p > 0$ or $p < 0$. But when $p = 0$, then $f$ is not 1-1 on any neighborhood of $p$. In this case you can see that $f$ does not map any open neighborhood of $0$ to an open set. Instead the image always contains $0$ as a minimum point. So Rudin has to make use of the additional requirement that the derivative of $f$ is non-singular show that $x_0$ has a neighborhood whose image is open.